# What's a polite way to ask if the interview would be face-to-face or Skype?

Tags: interviewing, internship

A company just asked me if I'm available for an interview but did not mention whether it's a face-to-face or Skype. I wanted to ask if she wants a Skype interview or prefers I went to her office?

I'm currently out of state, so I can only do Skype interviews.

Comment: How did they ask you for interview (email, phone)? This is important so you can decide the mean you will use for responding.

Comment: @GrayCygnus they asked through e-mail

Comment: @MisterPositive Since they invited me through e-mail, I haven't replied to their message yet

Comment: @MisterPositive I would have to relocate if they offered me the job

Comment: You seem to be overthinking this. It's in no way impolite to discuss the logistics of the interview. Just ask.

Comment: Are you temporarily out of state, or do you currently live in a different state? Did you in any way indicate where you live as part of the application process?  This could be relevant information for them, both for the interview process and whether or not they would pay for relocation.  If they already know where you are, the question makes a lot more sense when you ask them.

Comment: @cdkMoose I currently live out of state, however I do plan on moving there in a few weeks. I assume that they don't know that I live out of state because I have never mentioned in.

Comment: So you're moving there whether you get this job or not?  In an early comment, you stated you'd have to relocate if you get the job.  That's two different situations.  Whatever the scenario, it is hard for them to handle it correctly if they don't have the information.  There's nothing wrong with asking because of the situation, in fact it's probably more wrong not to provide the info.

Comment: @cdkMoose My plan was to relocate there to find better opportunities because I've made a decision that I really want to work in that area. The only reason why I haven't move yet is because I'm still waiting for my current lease to end. I have sent them a reply, asking how the interview is going to take place and let them know that I currently live out of state,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just be honest and clear, without an elaborate explanation. Explain that you are out of states and that you would know if it is possible to have the interview via Skype. Also, I suggest you propose them to have a face-to-face interview when you come back, as an alternative given the Skype interview is not an option.

You say they reached you via e-mail, so you should ask how/where the interview is taking place when you reply to them (given that you confirm your desire of being interviewed).

Answer (score 5):

Call your contact back, and say, "I am currently out of state.  Is it possible to do a Skype interview?"

The worst that can happen is that you'll be told "no", and you'll either have to pass on the interview or work out some other solution.  People are in this situation every day, so don't spend a lot of time being anxious about the outcome.   Do your best!